# flutter cant load image from network

Tags: flutter

```dart
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                snapshot.data[index].poster),
            // backgroundImage:
            // NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].poster),
          ),
          title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
          //subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].stroyLine)
        );
      },
    );
```

here is the error

```
I/flutter ( 4457): CacheManager: Failed to download file from movies\May2020\Qxl0LyTx7jxab3uPRyOI.jpg with error:
I/flutter ( 4457): Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI movies%5CMay2020%5CQxl0LyTx7jxab3uPRyOI.jpg
```

Comment: The image link that you provided the `CachedNetworkImageProvider` is not a valid URL

Comment: the error you mention says clearly what is going wrong - Failed to download file from `url` , that means url isn't correct.

Comment: yes the URL wasn't correct I gave it the correct path and can't display the image when I gave it one image link it works, it don't work with the list, I am new to flutter .....the URL came from the API is like  "poster": "movies\\May2020\\Qxl0LyTx7jxab3uPRyOI.jpg", is these a problem?